# Guessing the number that the user has thought with java (arrays)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm kind of new at programming and our teacher asked us to make a programme that can guess the number the user has thought using arrays. I did this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Think a number between 1 and 100");
        int array[] = new int[100];

        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            array[x] = (int) ((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        }
        //This allow us to fill the array with random numbers, without caring if they are repeated or not.
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < 100; j++) {
                while (true) {
                    if (i != j && array[i] == array[j]) {
                        array[j] = (int) ((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                    } else
                        break;
                }
                //If a number is repeated, this will swap that number with another number.
            }
        }

        //Now we have filled the array. We ask the user:
        for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
            System.out.println("¿Is it your number " + array[y] + "?");
            String respuesta = entrada.next();
            switch (respuesta) {
                case "Yes":
                    System.out.println("I knew it! I only needed " + y + " trys!");
                    break;
                case "No":
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is still throwing errors when I execute it, like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
    at Ejercicio11.main(Ejercicio11.java:25).
```

I have tried to debug it but I'm still learning how to do it and I cannot find the mistake. Can someone help me identify where the error is and how can I fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: in case you don't know just a hint to interpret this exception: You got an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - that usually means you try to use an index on your array that does not exist (e.g. your array is empty and you try to use the third element). It also tells you which method has thrown it (here your main) and at which line number there error happened (here 25)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition of your inner for loop should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
```

(The condition is *j < 100*, not *i < 100*)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realize and I checked it like four times! Now it works, thanks!. Edit: I realised also that the number of trys should be (y+1).